# libhdf5.so.200 can't open shared object file: no such file or directory (repost)

Tags: python, directory, hdf5

I have installed pytorch and then nest-simulator in a conda virtual environment. When I import them, pytorch import fine but nest-simulator says ImportError: libhdf5.so.200: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

I have tried searching for the file in my file manager, and it does seem to exist in the hdf5 directory under my virtual environment packages folder.

[image]

I've tried reinstalling hdf5, but to no avail.

Extra info:

```
(testenv) matteo@masked-hero:~$ python -c 'import nest'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/matteo/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/nest/__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    from .ll_api_kernel_attributes import KernelAttribute  # noqa
  File "/home/matteo/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/nest/ll_api_kernel_attributes.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .ll_api import sr, stack_checker, sps, spp
  File "/home/matteo/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/nest/ll_api.py", line 54, in <module>
    from . import pynestkernel as kernel  # noqa pylint: disable=no-name-in-module
ImportError: libhdf5.so.200: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Show us your `environment.yml` file (hopefully [pruned down](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce the symptom without lots of other cruft in there). Tell us about your OS version. Show us `$ which hdf5` or whatever you're running, and show us `ldd` output for it so we can see which libraries are found / not found.

Comment: where do i find the .yml file?

Comment: OS is linux mint 20.04, and which hdf5 gives no output. I am trying to import pynest and pytorch in jupyter lab.

Comment: You told us you setup a conda environment. Either you're doing something crazy like running a bash script which deletes then creates a named environment, and then does multiple package installs. Or you went the sane route and created `environment.yml` at top level so you can edit it and then `$ conda env update` to make it effective. You need the .yml if you want reproducibility. And yes, you want reproducibility. // Paste in a console session which reproduces the error, e.g. `$ python -c 'import pynest'` or whatever is failing.

Comment: i used conda create --name testenv python=3.10. I edited the question to include the output of `python -c 'import nest'`